# how to update getting results from an entry box automatically?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to update getting results from an entry box in a way that when an integer enters, the equivalent rows of entry boxes appear below that. I have written the below code to make it work using a button. However, I want to make it happen automatically without a button as I entered the number, the rows update. I checked one way of doing that is using the `after()`. I placed after `after()` in the function and out of the function but it is not working.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

n_para = IntVar()

label1 = Label(root, text="Numeric parameters")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=n_para)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)

def update():
    for i in range(1, n_para.get()+1):
        entryX = Entry(root)
        entryX.grid(row=i+1, column=0)

        entryY = Entry(root)
        entryY.grid(row=i+1, column=1)

        entryZ = Entry(root)
        entryZ.grid(row=i+1, column=2)

        root.after(100, update)

root.after(1, update)

button1 = Button(root, text="update", command=update)
button1.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using the `<KeyRelease>` event bind.

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_focus_out(event):
    label.configure(text=inputtxt.get())


root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

inputtxt = tk.Entry()
  
inputtxt.pack()

root.bind("<KeyRelease>", on_focus_out)

root.mainloop()
```

This types the text entered in real-time.

Edited Code with OP's requirement:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

n_para = IntVar()

label1 = Label(root, text="Numeric parameters")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=n_para)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)

def upd(event):
    x = entry1.get()
    if not x.isnumeric():
        x = 0
    for i in range(1, int(x)+1):
        entryX = Entry(root)
        entryX.grid(row=i+1, column=0)

        entryY = Entry(root)
        entryY.grid(row=i+1, column=1)

        entryZ = Entry(root)
        entryZ.grid(row=i+1, column=2)

#        root.after(100, update)

root.bind("<KeyRelease>", upd)

# button1 = Button(root, text="update", command=update)
# button1.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. unfortunately, I don't understand how to apply that to my case. I can do a similar thing using after() for your example as we enter the number the results updates in the label. but in my case, it doesn't work.

Comment: @PSB Your code seems to make a `3 by x` matrix of entries depending upon the input in the `entry1`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, but `x by 3`

Comment: @PSB I have added the code after combining mine with yours, sorry for the delay I just saw the comment

Comment: Thanks so much. I wonder how would I then get values from new entries. I know it is not asked in my question. Should I append them to a list?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible that way. You are making entries in a for loop and all of them have the same variable name. I tried using the `bind` function but it only detects the text inside the last row of entries.